# "media type unrecognized" when uploading an image to Twitter using npm twit

Tags: node.js, express, twitter

I am working on an express node app that posts to twitter when a user inputs an image into a form. I am saving the image locally before uploading, which works. After I encode the file to base64, I try to upload the base64-encoded file to Twitter using twit's media/upload feature. When I do this, I get an error saying "media type unrecognized."

Here is my code:

```
app.post('/tweet', function(req, res){
   var time = new Date().getTime()
   let image = req.files.image
   var imgpath = './images/img' + time + '.jpg'

   image.mv(imgpath, function(err) {
       if (err){
         return res.status(500).send(err);
       }
   });
   var b64content = fs.readFileSync(imgpath, { encoding: 'base64' })

       T.post('media/upload', {media: b64content}, function(err, data, res) {
           if (err) console.log(err);
           console.log(data);
           T.post('statuses/update', {status: 'posted picture at: ' + time, media_ids: [data.media_id_string]}, function(err, params, res) {
           if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log(params);
        });
    });


   return res.redirect('/')
})
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got it!. I needed to put the `T.post` code in the brackets of `image.mv`'s function

Answer (score 0):

use `postMediaChunked` function

```
var filePath = '/absolute/path/to/file.png'
T.postMediaChunked({ file_path: filePath }, function (err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: a verbal explanation would be a very helpful addition to your answer