# Twitter API tells me " media type unrecognized." for images that always worked

Tags: php, image, twitter

> Edit 2020-28-02: It was an error on Twitter's side (thanks for the useful [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59858831/twitter-api-tells-me-media-type-unrecognized-for-images-that-always-worked#comment105890414_59858995)). I keep the
>   question up in spite of the down votes because it could happen again, and this could be useful for others with the same error "media type unrecognized".

I have a small app, me as the sole user, updating my thematic twitter daily. By pressing a button it posts one much smaller than 5MB jpg image every day from a pool of 12. It worked for months like this. Now Twitter tells me: "media type unrecognized."

[This is one of the images](https://yzahk.in/nazar-images/nazar-map4.jpg).

Symptoms:

- I can't upload the same image to Twitter on the website either. So I assume
  my images got banned, from uploading.
- I can upload png version of the same image to the website but not by my PHP software. And that is strange.
- I can upload a different image both from my PHP script and on Twitter website.

I use [this class](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) for my PHP script

Only error in my log is this:

> [22-Jan-2020 08:45:37 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property:
>   stdClass::$media_id_string in /home/ABC/public_html/XYZ.php on line
>   205

It simply means: the upload was not successful, so Twitter API did not respond with a media ID (at this point it is NULL)

This is my script (around this there is logic to decide the text and for logging me in):

```
require_once 'twitteroauth/autoload.php';
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'my consumer key');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'my consumer secret');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', 'my access token');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', 'my access secret');

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

$postfields = array(
    'media' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($image))
);

$media = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => $image]);

$parameters = [
            'status' => 'my tweet text, never longer than 200 chars'
            'media_ids' => $media->media_id_string
];

$result = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);
```

I repeat: this worked without a problem for months, I did not change anything in it. It just started to post the text without the image.

I realize there are [*several*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019575/media-type-unrecognized-when-uploading-an-image-to-twitter-using-npm-twit) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536867/twitter-api-upload-image-always-return-error-media-type-unrecognized) *[questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261958/twitter-api-media-upload-400-bad-request-media-type-unrecognized)* [about](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/issues/572) similar problem with similar error message out there, but non of the solutions worked for me.

- I regenerated my access token and secret: nothing changed
- I tried chunked upload: same result
- I made new jpg files with 1 pixel smaller dimension so I trick Twitter it might be another image: it did not trick twitter
- I tried to `sleep(1)` after the upload line: that was un-logical and silly on my part (but I thought might be the upload was slow, as one of the folks having the same problem with javascript version solved it like this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter's documentation states:

> Ensure the POST is a multipart/form-data request. Either upload the raw binary (media parameter) of the file, or its base64-encoded contents (media_data parameter). Use raw binary when possible, because base64 encoding results in larger file sizes

However it looks like you are uploading base64-encoded contents, while using the media parameter. Try changing the media parameter to media_data.

It's likely a recent change or one that is only recently enforced, hence it working before for you.

Comment: I already tried that based on another question here. It changed nothing. Still no media id, still posting only the text.

Comment: Also raw binary with media parameter does the same.

Comment: Well, you can have more than one problem. It definitely needs to be set to media_data. The fact that you can't upload the same image on the website either suggests this is **not** an API problem, but an image problem (or a Twitter problem, like you said, perhaps it is being blocked).

Comment: Yeah I leave it like that after this.

Also this is why I ended up asking the question. The point is to put it out there this can happen. I think my use case of the API is legit, but from an automatic moderation stand point it could be seen as spam posting the same 12 images every day. As a next step I will try to contact Twitter about it.

Comment: There was a temporary issue yesterday (Jan 22) with media uploads, that should now be resolved.